# Merging cells in address (Excel)

Tags: excel, merge, cells

Is there any way to merge cells in address? For example, I want to use the RANK fuction on different columns, like:

```
=RANK(A1;A:A AND C:C AND D2:D10).
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all functions allow it but you can use a `"union"` in `RANK` function, e.g. like this:

`=RANK(A2,(A$2:A$10;C$2:C$10;D$2:D$10))`